# Transitioning from login view controllers to the main page

Tags: ios, swift, authentication

I have a little app that I'm building and wanted some opinions on the way I'm implementing login. Here's my plan:

1) Open app

2) Load ContainerViewController (The container view controller will play a little animation that shows the app is doing some loading)

3) The ContainerViewController checks if a token exists in the keychain. If a token does exist, then check if its valid or not.

3a) If the token is valid, add HomeViewController (a view controller that is the root of a navigation controller that is basically the main page of the app) as a child view controller.

3b) If the token is invalid, add LoginViewController (a view controller that basically handles the signing in process) as a child view controller.

If you sign in successfully at the login page, loginviewcontroller will be removed as a child and homeviewcontroller will be added as a child.

Is using container and child view controllers the right way to go about handling the opening of the app? By the way, I'm building it completely programmatically, which means I'm not using storyboards so segues can't be used (unless I'm totally wrong there). Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right approach to implementing the login process. In short Up on login, you check for the token, if it is there and valid you present the MainViewController. Else you present the LoginViewController.

PS(Thumbs up for developing it programatically! I like that way as well)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply! I'm gonna wait for a couple more responses and see other approaches before I select an answer.

Comment: Also, by "presenting controllers", you mean removing and adding as child view controllers right?

Comment: when you login, the loginVC is useless so no reason to keep it in the memory! better to remove it as you suggested.